# c# - select rows from a datatable that contain a certain dd/mm

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, select, datatable

I'm trying to select rows from a datatable that a have a datetime column that contains a certain dd/mm In my **windows forms application using C#**, how can this be done? I know the expressions are similar to SQL.

DataType of column is datetime, for example: 09/03/2017 13:26:40 

 so far i have tried the below but it just returns an exception:

```
string selectExpression = "colDate LIKE '%09/03%'";
DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select(selectExpression);
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. You've already got one product specific answer...

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: To all the people asking for dbms, this is about DataSets, not some database system.

Comment: You can easily do this using LINQ. DataSets support LINQ.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, this a C# winforms program. I am using DataTable.Select() which uses similar queries/expressions to SQL

Comment: @PaulAlexander tried what i answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you are apply string filter to DateTime. You can use it of the type if colDate is string then I tested your code and its working.

To filter the DataTable column with DateTime type you can use linQ query like given as under.

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Field<DateTime>("colDate").Day == 9
           && r.Field<DateTime>("colDate").Month == 3);
```